# CoreBluetooth GAP service - how to broadcast and update service characteristics dynamically?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am new to Bluetooth and CoreBluetooth and am trying to create a test app that:

- uses an iOS device as a GAP service broadcaster
- uses the same iOS Device to discover other iOS Devices broadcasting the same service
- any app broadcasting a service can dynamically update a service characteristic and another number of devices to dynamically see the updated characteristic.

The dynamic nature doesn't have to be immediate/realtime but near realtime would be nice. Interactive would be a bonus.

In essence, id love a local, multicast equivalent with out relying on any connection or centrals. For my application use case there is no need for a central and peripheral to negotiate a connection. All data is broadcast, anonymized and meant to be read only.

However, whenever I attempt to query a service from a discovered peripheral - its services are nil, and  it says I have to connect to it to discover its characteristics.

```
2020-03-19 12:27:15.842128-0400 no-go[374:89822] [CoreBluetooth] API MISUSE: <CBPeripheral: 0x17d925b0, identifier = <UUID HERE>, name = SERVICE_NAME, state = disconnected> can only accept commands while in the connected state
```

Is it possible to create a broadcast mode GAP service with dynamic updates on iOS and have them be dynamically updated?

Or am I misunderstanding Centrals and connections and its ok to do super light weight connections coming up and down repeatedly and dynamically?

My current attempt sets up:

- 1 'hard coded' service UUID that all broadcast iOS device share
- 2 'hard coded'  characteristic UUIDs that all broadcast iOS device share
- Each broadcast iOS device creates a `CBMutableCharacteristic` for the characteristic IDs - each with read only and nil values in expectation it will be *updated dynamically* later.
- Each device creates a `CBPeripheralManager` to broadcast the service
- Each device creates a `CBCentralManager` to discover other broadcasters for the specific service UUID

Discovery code:

```
        self.centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [ self.service ], options: nil)
        print("Started Listening")
```

Devices DO discover when one another become active (app launch) - via the central delegate method:

```
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
```

However, my discovered peripheral is not able to be introspected, I get the not connected error above.

Any pointers would be welcome

Answer (score 1):

1.) Inside the `func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber)` delegate method check that `central.state == .poweredOn`

2.) Then check that peripheral isn't connected yet and connect to the peripheral:

```swift
if peripheral.state == .disconnected {
    central.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}
```